# How is this virtual address calculated in this question? I have the answer but, I don't understand how the answer was reached

Tags: operating-system, paging, calculation

The question says

> Given a two-level page table with 4-KB pages and. Assume that each level uses 10
> bits. What would be the virtual address if PT1=2, PT2=3, offset=5?

The given answer is

> (2×2^22)+(3×2^12)+5=8400901

I get that because the pages are size 4-KB that the PT should be multiplied by 2^12. But where does the 2^22 come from?

Answer (score 0):

A clearer way to write the answer is:

```
2 << (10 + 12) + 3 * << 12 + 5 = 8400901
```

This is like:

```
2 << (BITS_IN_PAGE_TABLE_INDEX + BITS_IN_OFFSET) + 3 * << BITS_IN_OFFSET + 5 = 8400901
```